# Oracle SQL sums

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help with the following sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75813f/12.

Here I want to fill the columns `colsumsum1` and `colsumsum2` within range of colmonth (1 to 5) where `colsumsum1` and `colsumsum2` are `0` with values where already exist.

E.g. for colx=x1 it should be filled with 87 respectively 125 and for colx=x2 with 58 and 96.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change column in `PARTITION BY`:

```
select 
  nvl(demo.colx, blamth.colx) as colx,
  nvl(demo.cola, blamth.cola) as cola,
  nvl(demo.colb, blamth.colb) as colb,
  nvl(demo.colc, blamth.colc) as colc,
  nvl(demo.colmonth, blamth.colmonth) as colmonth,
  nvl(demo.colsum1, 0) as colsum1,
  nvl(demo.colsum2, 0) as colsum2,
  sum(nvl(demo.colsum1, 0)) over (partition by blamth.colx) as colsumsum1,
  sum(nvl(demo.colsum2, 0)) over (partition by blamth.colx) as colsumsum2  
from demo right outer join blamth
on demo.colx = blamth.colx and
   demo.colmonth = blamth.colmonth
order by 1,5;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=51d46afbdc462ebc2165f2f2626bb5e0)**

Comment: Awesome! I will check this solution on my data.

Comment: I've checked the solution and it is OK. Now I want another column colsummonth which sums all values from a month and put this sum in row for this month. For colmonth='01' it should be colsum1+colsum1+... for all colx with this month. See my fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75813f/17